# Countable $\varepsilon$-net of measurable sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lindelof-spaces

Let $I=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{A}$ is the family that contains all the Lebesgue measurable sets of $I$, for any $A_1,A_2\in \mathcal{A}$, we define a metric
$$d(A_1,A_2)=\int |1_{A_1}-1_{A_2}|.$$

A $\varepsilon$-net of $\mathcal{A}$ is a sub-family $\mathcal{A}'\subset \mathcal{A}$ such that
$$\forall A\in \mathcal{A},\exists A'\in \mathcal{A}',~s.t.~d(A,A')\le \varepsilon.$$

My question is:

> For all $\varepsilon>0$, does there exist a countable $\varepsilon$-net for $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Is it a metric ? It seems that the distance between two sets of measure $0$ is also $0$.

Comment: Yes, but we can quotient on the equivalent relation $A_1\sim A_2$ iff $d(A_1,A_2)=0$ if needed.

Comment: Note that this is the same as the standard metric on a measure space $d(A,B) = \mu(A\Delta B)$ and this is a separable pseudometric space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I also find this wiki page is useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Separable_%CF%83-algebras

Comment: And for (pseudo)metric spaces your net property is equivalent to separability of the measure space. And Lebesgue measure is separable (classical fact, that Wikipedia also mentions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make $d$ a metric you have to think of your set as a subset of $L^{1}$ by identifying sets which differ only by a null set. In  that case the assertion is true. Consider finite disjoint unions of intervals with rational end points and their characteristic functions. Characteristic function of any $A \in\mathcal A$ can be approximated in $L^{1}$ norm by those of  finite disjoint unions of intervals and then we can approximate these intervals by those with rational end points which proves the assertion.